# Azure Database Migration Service failed

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration

I'm testing migration on a super small DB ~10 Mb.

So, i've moved schema to Azure SQL Database using `Data Migration Assistant`. And i've tested migration by this app, its working, cool!

But i wanna set up online migration and make downtime of service ~= 0

When i'm running online migration using `Azure Database Migration Service` after 25 minutes i got next message: `"Task '84a6ab96-3c00-4458-aba3-1ab0735dcb95' was suspended due to 8 successive recovery failures"`

Migration from on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL Database. Port 1433 opens on a firewall.

Migration with Data Migration Assistance working good, but its not online (without downtime)

What i'm doing wrong? where i can find any logs? Please help if anyone know how to fight it!

Comment: Could you please tell me if all tables haven primary key indexes?

Comment: yes, there are 2 tables with primary key. and if i understand correctly, my network setting correct, cause when i set up source and target server, there is no any errors.
one more thing, i tried to migrate only schema and it's working. but online migration not.

Comment: Online migration won't work if some tables are heaps.

Comment: Are any of those tables using SQL variant data types?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know exactly, how can i check it?

Comment: It seems the database has just a few tables, please examine table data types. Make sure all tables have the "yellow key" set. SQL Server Management Studio will help you do these tasks. Download it for free.

Comment: i've checked, there is no variant data types. What is the "yellow key"? i have access through the MSSMS.

Comment: Look at this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzUcN.png

Comment: in my 2 tables i have no "yellow keys", there are 1 key in 1 table and its a grey. Could you please tell me what i have to change? or maybe you have a better way to migrate DB to Azure wih minimum downtime?